# Zipping large quantity of files in a directory using c# ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, zip, compression

I use ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib in my c# code which  zips old log files in a directory .The script works well and the size of the output zip file is of decent size .However my problem is that i have a directory with 88GB of files which are sized in  5-10mb range,I read online that maximum size of the zip file is 4GB , will the script / compression work for this quantity and not throw an error ? i  dont want to try it since these files are from a production application. Can anyone please give me some insights , comments or thoughts. Thanks in advance

Comment: You know, you could create 100gb of files on your hd and then zip them :-) (or in the end, even of 5 gb, the limit was 4 gb and 65535 files)

Comment: From the [faq](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FAQ) Zip64 is supported, so there should be a way to generate a zip with size > 4gb

Answer (score 0):

Did you try? Did you run into a problem? SharpZipLib supports the Zip64 format extensions, so it should be able to create zip files much larger than 4 GB.